# Encoding to be used for ANSI - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, encoding

What encoding we need to use to save a file as text file(of type ANSI) - While saving the text file ANSI encoding to be used.
What to be used here, not seeing ANSI as an option

vb.net code - what should be given after Encoding.?

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("d:\binary.txt", strTemp, True,System.Text.Encoding.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ANSI is not an encoding, it is just a generic name for "not Unicode".  You typically use Encoding.Default, the same code page as the one your operating system uses.  At least all of the programs that run on that machine can read the file without trouble.

Comment: which is why I use UTF8 Encoding whenever possible :)

Answer (score 1):

it works for me:

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a stream writer with System encoding as default:

```
Dim myfilepath as String = "C:/"
Dim myappendingoption as boolean = True 'True: append text to file, False: overwrite
Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(myfilepath, myappendingoption, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
sw.Write("sometext")
sw.Close()
```